# What is the difference between 「帰る」and 「帰れる」？

Tags: words, conjugations, potential-form

I believe the latter is not the passive form of 帰る, so what makes it different?

Answer (score 1):

【帰る】 is the plain form.

【帰れる】 is the potential form, so to express that you can go back.